# How to create a custom event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

How is it possible to create a custom event handler and put some default variables in it??

## scope A:

```
var a = 'weee';
var b = 'hmm';
var click = function(){
    alert(a+' '+b);
}
```

## scope B:

```
$('#btn').click = click;
```

When the button is clicked var `a` and `b` is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$('#btn').click(click);
```

or

```
var a = 'weee';
var b = 'hmm';
$('#btn').click(function(){
    alert(a+' '+b);
});
```

or

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var a = 'weee';
    var b = 'hmm';
    alert(a+' '+b);
});
```

The problem when you do

```
$('#btn').click = click;
```

is that instead of binding your function to the `"click"` event, you're replacing the jQuery `click` function defined [here](http://api.jquery.com/click/) by your own function.

Comment: i m not a js guy..but i want to know ... would you mind explain reason ??

Answer (score 2):

try simply with

```
$('#btn').click(click);
```